# What is the minimum privilege required to create a full text index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index, permissions

I just created a full text catalog on my database.  I now have a developer who needs the ability to create full text indexes on the tables in this database.

The suggestion given in a [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/135317/how-to-get-permission-to-create-full-text-index) was to grant db owner to the user. I'd really like to avoid giving such a high level of access.

Is there any way to do this without granting dbo? I wasn't able to find anything regarding the permissions aspect on BOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317(v=sql.105).aspx) :

> **User must have REFERENCES permission on the full-text catalog and have ALTER permission on the table or indexed view**, or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, or db_owner, or db_ddladmin fixed database roles.
>
> If SET STOPLIST is specified, the user must have REFERENCES permission on the specified stoplist. The owner of the STOPLIST can grant this permission.
>
> The public is granted REFERENCE permission to the default stoplist that is shipped with SQL Server.

Suggest you create a role and add the dev to the role. Just grant permissions to the role.

Answer (score 2):

Someone can create indexes if they have been granted db_ddladmin or if their user is the owner for that table, database, or has been granted db_owner.